# app with sockets, showing alerts returns to the root controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, uialertview

In an app that I'm building using SocketRocket is a websockets client and when there is an alert or error the server sends an appropriate message to the app.

All the sockets communication code, for example the important:

```
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message {[...] }
```

exist within the root viewcontroller of the app.

All the message processing is happening at another class and the user navigates freely through the app.

When I want to show though a simple alert with the message received from the server (either UIAlertView or UIAlertController) and an "OK" button (to just dismiss it),  as soon as the user clicks the "OK" button they are returned to the first (root) view controller which in my case is a login credentials screen.

At present the code firing the alerts is within the didReceiveMessage in the root controller.

```
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message {

NSData *data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
syncDevices *syncDev = [syncDevices new];

NSArray *devArr;

devArr = [syncDev parseDeviceXMLData:data];

  if (devArr.count > 0) {

    if ([devArr[0]  isEqual: @"error"]) {
        // error message receved, display an alert!

        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!"
                                                             message:devArr[1]
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [errorAlert show];

        return;

    } 
  }
}
```

Is it possible for the user to dismiss the alert AND stay on the same screen as they were? How do I do that?

I want to avoid if possible having to do a func in every screen to display the alert...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown has nothing related to navigation between different views, as far as I can see. Pressing OK button will change views (push or pop) only, if you have implemented some UIAlertViewDelegate method and there manually do it.

**Suggestion**: change `delegate:self` to `delegate:nil` to disable all possible side-effects. Now pressing OK button should just remove the popup and nothing else.